# PHP Pipeline, why is the object getting cloned?

Tags: php

I was looking at some php code and stumbled on a pipeline script. In the method to add something to the pipeline:

```
public function pipe(callable $stage)
{
    $pipeline = clone $this;
    $pipeline->stages[] = $stage;
    return $pipeline;
}
```

The object is getting cloned, and returned. 
Could someone explain me the advantages of this approach, 
wouldn't the following code return the same results?

```
public function pipe(callable $stage)
{       
    $this->stages[] = $stage;
    return $this;
}
```

Comment: I guess the best explanation (and probably with examples) can be provided by the author of the library.

Comment: @axiac Completely agree with you! But 9 out of 10 when people use in php keyword `clone` - they wanna solve one particular problem...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

No, it won't return the same. `Clone` creates a copy of the object, which is sometimes the desired behaviour.

```
class WithoutClone {
    public $var = 5;

    public function pipe(callable $stage)
    {       
        $this->stages[] = $stage;
        return $this;
    }
}

$obj = new WithoutClone();
$pipe = $obj->pipe(...);
$obj->var = 10;
echo $pipe->var; // Will echo 10, since $pipe and $obj are the same object 
                 // (just another variable-name, but referencing to the same instance);

// ----

class Withlone {
    public $var = 5;

    public function pipe(callable $stage)
    {       
        $pipeline = clone $this;
        $pipeline->stages[] = $stage;
        return $pipeline;
    }
}

$obj = new WithClone();
$pipe = $obj->pipe(...);
$obj->var = 10;
echo $pipe->var; // Will echo 5, since pipe is a clone (different object);
```

Comment: clone() creates a copy of an object using the __clone() method and could still have sides effects if the cloned object has attributes that are reference object.